# Is there a use case for not using "this" when calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, garbage-collection

I was just implementing the Dispose pattern, and when I just typed the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` line, I was wondering if there is ever a use case for using something other than `this` as the parameter to the method.

This is the typical pattern:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  // right here
}
```

Does it ever make sense to call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` with something other than `this`?

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(foo);  // should this ever happen?
}
```

Comment: The only time I could imagine that being useful is if you are using a third party class that has a finalizer and a Dispose() method but it doesn't call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` itself for some reason. Then you could theoretically fix it up by calling SuppressFinalize() for the object explicity after you called Dispose() for it. But that sounds pretty far-fetched.

Comment: Of course there are uses, just not very common ones. In things like an object pool. But it's not a good question for SO.

Comment: Not many scenarios really. Also according to the question on the sidebar (When should I use GC.SupressFinalize()?), the top answer says |Don't be tempted to call SuppressFinalize on other objects mind you. That's a serious defect waiting to happen.|

Comment: Yes, you could use something other than 'this', but only if you use VB.NET for calling the method. GC.SuppressFinalize(Me) :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Perhaps this isn't the best question for SO, but I think the insight provided by the comments has been helpful. I'm now curious as to what those uncommon use cases are.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think your comment would be good as an answer. Maybe it shouldn't be the accepted answer, but still worth an upvote, IMO.

Comment: It probably requires the `this` reference because otherwise, the caller might have been inlined, so just examining the caller would suppress finalization for the wrong object.

Comment: @milan-j sooo close... but disregarding self (IronPython, and others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx

It is in fact possible that your example: GC.SuppressFinalize(foo)
will be used in certain scenarios, but not in the scenario of the common dispose pattern.

In example you might want to write some kind of dispose management pattern for many objects instead of implementing the common dispose pattern from within your object. another option is if you want an object to remain suppressed and later on maybe claim it? never done that.. but it's possible.

So possible yes.. likely to happen no - and probably never.